Looking for an old Disney / nick movie that isn't listed in forums I've seen?
I remember watching it as a kid (I was born in 99), so roughly between 2003 and 2010. I remember there was a person in the movie playing a celebrity, and these kids, which are the main character, become friends with him and get invited to his party, and they see "the popular kids" from their school there. The popular kids don't think that the main characters are invited, and then the celebrity comes over and proves that they're invited and good friends of his. The next day, the popular kids are talking about the party at school and deny the fact that the main characters where at it. I distinctly remember some sort of scene at a police station as well.

It must be Confessions of a Teenage Drama Queen, where the main character is played by Lindsay Lohan is a 15 year old girl who admires Rock Band Sidarthur. But soon she knows that band is breaking and her rival girls are going to their last concert and she is not getting any pass. 
She with her friend go there uninvited but can't able to see the concert. They even try to crash the after concert party but got thrown out. But they see the lead singer of the band uncontrolled drunk, they help him. There is also a police scene here. Then these both girls attend the party with invitation. 
But in school, rival girls (popular girls) deny their presence. The main girl's all lies got busted and now her truth is also not believable to anyone and then the lead band singer appears to return something left by the girl in the party. And then the happy ending!
